# How from my android app get the EXACT latitude/longitude fast as possible?

Tags: android, geolocation, location, android-location, android-gps

Often when I request the latitude/longitude I receive an approximate value (around 300m of my actual position) and sometime it's also take a very long time to retrieve the latitude/longitude. but when I open google map my position is always very accurate and very fast to retrieve. So what is the good way to do in my android app to retrieve my real position in the most fastest way?

Answer (score 0):

You can call requestLocationUpdates(). However calling this to often can drain somebodies battery much quicker so it is not recommended unless it is necessary for the function of the app.

https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current